# When does free game time for ESO start?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I'm thinking of buying Elder Scrolls Online since its currently on sale. With this purchase I'll get free in-game time, but I don't think I'll start to play it yet.

When does this free game time start to count down? Is it when I install it? When I make an ESO account? Or does it start counting down at some other point?

Comment: An fyi, activating before Mar 17th (Tamriel release) should be the best way to maximize crowns _ I was trying to find the blog article about that to ask a question here just now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the game time would start from the moment you apply your key (either your game key, or the game time card key) to your account, or upon applying it when creating an account.

Though I can't give you an explicit answer specific to ESO, this is a structure shared by most paid MMOs, like World of Warcraft and so on.

That said, it should be safe buying the game now and not making an account until you want to start playing. To be absolutely safe, you could try checking with the publisher, if they respond in time.